# Mounting remote file-system or directory into local Linux machine

Tags: sshfs

How to mount remote linux filesystem or directory into local linux machine. Let's say if there is a remote directory and I want to access its all content as if it is in my local hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

To mount remote directory into local machine, 1st make sure you have ssh access to the machine. And then try with:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other <remote user>@<remote ip>:<remote directory> <local directory>
```

This is for ubuntu. For fedora replace sudo with yum and so on and so forth.